# MVVM and serialization of model components

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, mvvm

On a preparation for a workshop for some apprentices, I came across a problem with saving the current state while following the MVVM pattern.

### Environment

First the **class diagramm** used for this question:
[image: class diagramm]

Secondly the **GUI**, so you can imagine what I expect the user to do: 
[image: GUI]

The MainMV creates a IngredientsVM for every ingredients there is (hard coded) and adds them into a list.
Then this list is bound to the UI. As the user changes the checkbox status the 'IsChecked' property of the IngredientVM changes accordingly.

The chosen ingredients via the UI are being saved in the Pizza object. So the pizza object contains a list of the chosen ingredients.

### The Problem

The user shall be able to export and import his choice. This sounds like a pretty easy thing to do but the problem comes with the MVVM pattern which I'd like to use for this exercise.

Since I have a list of Ingredients that is set, I already have instances of these classes. If I save and load them by serialization I get another instance of the serialized classes. So I end up with a list of all ingredients and a list with the chosen ingredients which are two **different** objects!
[image: workflow]

### Possible Solutions

I came across some solutions but I don't know which one fits the idea of the MVVM pattern best:

1. **Set the checkbox status according to the imported ingredient objects.** 
    That means I check if the name of an ingredient from the import is the same as in one of the IngredientVMs. If so I set the IsChecked to true. 
   But I feel like this is very poor way to code.
2. **Serialize the all IngredientVMs**
   I just serialize one level above. This way I get all Ingredients with their state (checked or not). 
   The downside with this solution is that if the user loads an older save file only the old ingredients are being loaded since it overloads the usual 'createIngrediants' process.
3. **Only export the ids**
   In my opinion this is the most suitable solution so far. I only export the ids of the selected ingredients. (I'd have to add ids to the class first of course) While importing I just look for the ids in the list and set those to checked.
   But somehow I feel like adding ids to something as simple as ingredients is wrong...

So, does any of you have a better solution to this problem?

Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: You have to supply code if you want better answer. Someone would take it and modify to show what is wrong. And I think you have design issue: what will you do when someone want to order 2 different pizzas (with different components)?

Comment: @Sinatr I didn't supply code on purpose since I don't want people to focus on the code but on the design.
More than one pizza: Then he'd had to define one pizza, export and then define the other one. It's just an project for apprentices.

Comment: If you add `Order`, then you will see mistake in design. You shouldn't reference `Ingredient` directly, because their `IsChecked` will be same in all pizzas. And 2 solutions: 1) copy list of all ingredients when you add new pizza to order 2) reference them by using id. If you do that there will be no problem with deserialization.

Comment: @Sinatr Ingredient doesn't contain the IsChecked property. The IngredientVM does. But yes like Siderite Zackwehdex mentioned adding an id seems to be the best solution so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need an id for an ingredient, that's for sure. If the name is unique, then it works just fine and it is human-readable as well, so option 3, which is the same as option 1 in this case. If the name is not unique, like you have different types of tomato or something, you use some other unique identifier.

MVVM handles the way the UI is separated from the underlying processes, importing and exporting data is not part of its purview, so the title of the question is a bit misleading, if you ask me.

Comment: Yeah you may be right about the title. I just thought since the structure with the VMs is caused by the MVVM pattern that it is connected. But on second thought you'd have the same problem with a form app of course.

And about the id part: I just feel like it's kind of an overhead to add an id to something simple as an one property class, don't you think? But if there's no other way..